# Escaped patten causes compile error

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex pattern:

```
r = New Regex("^((\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)(,(\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|[^,]*))*)$");
```

This is causing this error: `"CS1002: ; expected"`

I can't see what is causing this.

Comment: post prev lines of code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is supposed to be C# you have to use lowercase for `new`:

```
r = new Regex("^((\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)(,(\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|[^,]*))*)$");
```

Comment: I don't believe I didn't see that!